# Deskjet 720C driver crash during print

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

My Deskjet 720C prints fine from my XP machine, but I recently got a Windows 7 machine and where the driver crashes.

I get the following error in the event log:

```
Naam van toepassing met fout: PrintIsolationHost.exe, versie: 6.1.7600.16385, tijdstempel: 0x4a5bd3b1
Naam van module met fout: HPVSCP50.DLL, versie: 1.0.0.6, tijdstempel: 0x4431bcd4
Uitzonderingscode: 0xc0000005
Foutoffset: 0x0000000000010af7
Id van proces met fout: 0x278
Starttijd van toepassing met fout: 0x01d042d750b1cb5a
Pad naar toepassing met fout: C:\Windows\system32\PrintIsolationHost.exe
Pad naar module met fout: C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\HPVSCP50.DLL
Rapport-id: 9b2c5372-aeca-11e4-ae83-180373c3b422
```

Answer (score 0):

The interesting information is this:

```
Pad naar module met fout: C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\HPVSCP50.DLL
```

This looks like a HP printer driver file. So go to the [HP website, download and install the latest printer driver](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?product=58707&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en).